# When RetryPrompt Dialog is called?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dialog, botframework, prompt

Sorry cause the question, It may be not really good.

I try to use validator when adding a TextPrompt (for example)

`AddDialog(new TextPrompt(ServerPrompt, Validator));`

The Validator function return `Task<bool>`.
And hope that when the validating failed, the [RetryPrompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptoptions?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) will be invoked.

But nope.

The Bot just retry the `ActiveDialog` without any thing else.
I Just want a helpful message will be sent to the user, give him some suggestion useful.

```
// Create prompt opts to prompt for the server name
var opts = new PromptOptions {
    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Which Server?"),
    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("May you enter wrong thing, please check again!"),
};
```

Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

When the result `Task<bool>` of Validator is false.